# When i add a custom error page, do i return the error status code also?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

i've created a general exception handler in de the `global_asax`.

In there i log the exception, and redirect to `/error`

In that controller, i show the view with a friendly message, and i also set the `Response.StatusCode = 500`;

And now i'm wondering if that is ok....

In my localhost `cassini` this works fine, but when deployed on `IIS` i get the standard `IIS 500 page` and not my custom friendly view.

Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx) property in your error handler:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

It will prevent IIS error pages from getting in the way. Also, make sure you've correctly configured [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in Web.config

Comment: By the way: i do NOT have the custom errors section, because i catch the error in the globalasax and from there rout to a specific url. Imo i don't have to provide a customerros section (because imp the customerrors section is used when you don't catch the errors yourself, that at that point asp.net catches it, looks at the customerrors section and routes to the url set in the customerrors section), or is that not correct?

Comment: Or should i have a remoteerros section with only the setting to 'on' and then no `defaultRedirect` attribute and no '`error' elements in it?

Comment: You're right, you can just handle it in Application_Error(). You can try it without customErrors